# Access section data from section items in react native SectionList

Tags: react-native

I need to access the information regarding the section (index, value) inside the renderItem in react-native SectionList. According to http://docs.w3cub.com/react_native/sectionlist/#renderitem section details can be passed via renderItem function. But in below code except the item all other values will be set to undefined. Is there any other possible way of doing it?

```
    render(){
            return(
                <SectionList
                    sections={this.props.itemList}
                    renderItem={(item,section) => this._renderNewItem(item,section)}
                    renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                />
            )
        }

_renderNewItem(item,section){
        console.log(item, "   ", section)
    }
```

Sample data structure

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`renderItem` prop passes a single parameter to the function. This parameter is an object includes item and section data.

> **renderItem:** (info: { item: Item, index: number, section: SectionT,
>   separators: { highlight: () => void, unhighlight: () => void,
>   updateProps: (select: 'leading' | 'trailing', newProps: Object) =>
>   void, }, }) => ?React.Element

To get the section data you can use it like below

```
renderItem={({ item, section }) => this._renderNewItem(item,section)}
```

**Update**

Adding a sample example to demonstrate how it works. [See it on snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/SkBWPCNhZ)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, SectionList } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
const data = [{key: 'New', data: [{name: 'Foo1'}, {name: 'Foo2'}]}, {key: 'Old', data: [{name:'Foo3'}, {name: 'Foo4'}]}];
export default class App extends Component {

  _renderItem = ({item, section}) => (<Text>{`${item.name}(${section.key})`}</Text>)

  _renderSectionHeader = ({section}) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>{section.key}</Text>
        </View>
      )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
            sections={data}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  sectionHeader: {
      height: 50,
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingLeft: 10
  },
  header: {
      fontSize: 20,
  }
});
```

Comment: I results as undefined

Comment: Can you add sample data structure please

Comment: I have added the sample data structure above. Key is used to display the section title and data are used to derive the rows of the particular section

Comment: @Shanaka updated answer with a working example. Please compare it with your code and try to find whats different and not working.

Comment: The same code gives me undefined when executing inside my project. It seems this is some bug in the version that I'm using. I'm currently using "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6" and "react-native": "0.44.0". When I test your code on expo v17.0.0 (which is equivalent to rn v 0.44.0 ) it gives the same undefined output. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Output of this will look like attached image Link
> ```
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7CLF.png  **Output of this solution image.**

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/7kYrk8kf   **Dummy JSON File URL Link for** this Demo.

I used above mentioned JSON with Section List in following way with the help of ***@bennygenel*** code.

```
 renderItem = ({ item, section }) => <Text>{`${item.title}`}</Text>;


renderSectionHeader = ({ section }) => {

return (
  /*  <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
    <Text style={styles.header}>{section.key}</Text>
  </View> */
 ****Custom Header Component ****
  <CellHeader title={section.title} />
);
 };

renderSectionList = () => {

return (
  <View>
    <SectionList
      sections={data1.results}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
    />
  </View>
);
```

};