# Accessing & Understanding of SectionList in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, reactive-programming, react-native-ios

I am a newbie in react native, I am from iOS Background. 
Can someone say me about Sectionlist inregards with iOS. I have gone through few tutorials official & blogs but could not understand.
I have a sampl json :

```
[{"key":"New","data":[{"name":"Foo1"},{"name":"Foo2"}]},{"key":"Old","data":[{"name":"Foo3"},{"name":"Foo4"}]}]
```

With a bit of understanding from “https://stackoverflow.com/a/46601402”, I am trying to access item name, I got the result, name being displayed. But when I changed the son to :

```
[{"key":"New","gender":"male","name":{"title":"mr","first":"janique","last":"costa"},"registered":"2014-09-22 22:38:28","phone":"(48) 4518-1459","cell":"(22) 3632-3660"},{"key":"New11111","gender":"male11111","name":{"title":"mr11111","first":"janique11111","last":"costa11111"},"registered":"2014-09-22 22:38:2811111","phone":"(48) 4518-145911111","cell":"(22) 3632-366011111"}]
```

and trying to access gender, I am getting error :”TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating `'section.data.length'`)”

```
_renderItem = ({ item, section }) => (<Text>{section.key}</Text>)

    _renderSectionHeader = ({ section }) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>{section.key}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

render() {
    return (


      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
            sections={data}
            renderItem={this._renderItem}
            renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
        />
      </View>


    );
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

As per [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html), the object passed to `sections` property has to be an array of object which has `data` property which must also be an array. The changes that you have done does not contain `data` part, so a valid JSON could be

```
[
  {
    key: "New1", 
    data: [{"gender":"male","name":{"title":"mr","first":"janique","last":"costa"},"registered":"2014-09-22 22:38:28","phone":"(48) 4518-1459","cell":"(22) 3632-3660"}]
  },
  {
    key: "New2", 
    data: [{"gender":"male11111","name":{"title":"mr11111","first":"janique11111","last":"costa11111"},"registered":"2014-09-22 22:38:2811111","phone":"(48) 4518-145911111","cell":"(22) 3632-366011111"}]
  },
  // When data is empty, send empty array as shown below not null or empty object
  {
    key: 'New3',
    data: []
  }
];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank U, I missed that, and the method callback was put in render function itself by mistake, and the JSON that i have shared is a valid one.